# How to use getAt() function in Java/Groovy?

Tags: java, grails, groovy

Recently I encountered the usage of the method `getAt()` in Java code. It is used to get the data from a URL (which is sent via GET method by form submit). The URL will be like:

```
http://192.168.27.55/flight/search?n=airchina
```

The method was used like `name=params.getAt("n")`. Then the data was passed to another function by `search("n",name)`. Can any one please brief me how it works?

Answer (score 3):

`getAt()` in Groovy has special meaning for collections. It allows one to access elements of the collection using the [subscript operator](http://groovy.codehaus.org/Operators).

Here's the documentation for `Map` and `List`: 
[`Map#getAt(key)`](http://groovy.codehaus.org/groovy-jdk/java/util/Map.html#getAt%28K%29)
[`List#getAt(index)`](http://groovy.codehaus.org/groovy-jdk/java/util/List.html#getAt%28int%29)

Since it's defined to support some syntactic sugar, you don't really see it ever called directly, since it enables you to instead do something like:

```
Map foo = [bar: 'baz']
assert foo['bar'] == 'baz'
```

In your particular case with `params`, you'd simply use:

```
params['n']
```

...to take advantage of `getAt()`. Alternatively, you could use:

```
params.n
// or
params.get('n')
```

Comment: Can u guess what will be stored in the variable 'name' [name=params.getAt("n")] in the above question..?

Comment: It probably would have been `airchina`, although you could simply write a log or use a debugger to figure out what the value is.

Comment: Ya. But am confused why they again used "n" also (like search(n,name)) while passing the value to other function. They can simply use like search(name) right..?

Comment: Yes. It's difficult to say what the original author's intentions were here.

Answer (score 0):

```
params.n
```

[documentation for params](http://grails.org/doc/latest/ref/Controllers/params.html)

Comment: As far as i know params is a hashmap. in groovy its ok to write either params.n or params.getAt('n')
Sry, im no native speaker, maybe i dont get your question right into my head :)